# Serialize HTML 5 Canvas to SVG to send to server

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using a whiteboard created using HTML5 canvas.
I'm using this codepen [link](https://codepen.io/michaelsboost/pen/cnCAL) as it is.
I have to serialize Canvas to SVG and send to backend to generate HTML file. I'm totally newbie to canvas.

I tried by following [link](https://gliffy.github.io/canvas2svg/) to serialize Canvas to SVG.

Below is the sample snippet from above link and given example:

```
var ctx = new C2S(500,500); 
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fillRect(100,100,100,100);
var myRectangle = ctx.getSerializedSvg(true);
```

I want to change that codepen project to support this serialization. I'm not able to understand how to implement in that code.

In my case, `ctx` is initialized as below:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

After including canvas2svg script and below line change, canvas whiteboard is not working. I know this could be because of different `ctx` i s initialized (without `myCanvas.getContext("2d")`)

```
var ctx = new C2S(500,500);
```

Can you please help me out to understand mistake I am doing. If not this, can you suggest any other approach for my requirement.

Comment: As per the documentation, `canvas2svg` does not work with preexisting on-page canvas element. It's not actually "canvas element to SVG graphics", it's "canvas _drawing instructions_ to SVG graphics", where the `CS()` constructor yields an object just that acts _like_ a canvas context, but doesn't draw anything at all, instead saving all the drawing instructions as SVG-serializable code. If you want a solution that lets you use a real on page canvas, this is not that solution. But: consider filing an issue on https://github.com/gliffy/canvas2svg/issues to request it?

Comment: Mike thanks for your comment. Can you please any alternative if you have?

Comment: I can't, because I've been working with JS and SVG for so long that if I need this, I would just sit down and write the functionality I need here myself. For someone who can't do that, I would recommend filing an issue to request `canvas2svg` to work with a dual real/proxy canvas, with the `getContext()` overloaded to yield a context reference with an updated prototype that both falls through to the original functions for everthing _and_ run the proxy code for SVG generation.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I found another alternative. I simply converted canvas to data url using ``canvas.toDataURL()`` and sent to backend api and inserted it in img tag  and created HTML file out of it. This served my purpose.

Comment: Sure, but no one would have recommended that because that has nothing to do with SVG, now you're just making a bitmap image =)